# First and last name fields not filled when using wp_insert_user

Tags: plugin-development, users, profiles

I've written a plugin to allow authentication to a WordPress install via an external API. Everything is working except the first and last names are not being set for the new WordPress user created by the plugin when a login attempt passes the external authentication.

Here's the really strange part: one of the selectable display names *is* the first and last names coming in from the external API.

```
$userdata = array( 'user_email' => $ext_user['email'],
                                'user_login' => $ext_user['email'],
                                'first_name' => $ext_user['firstName'],
                                'last_name' => $ext_user['lastName'],
                                'role' => $user_role
                                );
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ); 

$user = new WP_User ($new_user_id);
```

That's the code I'm using to create the new users. I have logged both `$ext_user['firstName']` and `$ext_user['lastName']` just before filling the `$userdata` array to ensure those values are coming through properly and they are. I can't understand how they can be in the Display Name field but the First Name and Last Name fields are blank. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:** This install runs the Cimy User Extra Fields plugin. At first, I thought this might be the culprit, but I disabled it and the issue persists. Maybe that's still the problem, but I don't know how to determine. Could this plugin replace the default first and last name fields?

Comment: Do you have access to the database? If yes, are the fields filled with the info? Maybe it is just a problem of listing that info in the dashboard

Comment: @KThemes I just took a look at the database, and it looks like the plugin I mentioned has hijacked the WP first and last name columns. Those don't exist in the user database at all.

Comment: After wp_insert_user, you could try running

 `update_user_meta( $new_user_id, "first_name",  $ext_user['firstName'] ) ;`

Comment: @czerspalace Your solution worked. Not sure why it came to that, but that fixed the problem. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: It worked because first_name and last_name are user meta fields. Totally forgot about that :)

Comment: @KThemes So, you can't set those when you create the user?

Comment: Of course you can set those. With the help of "update_user_meta" as @czerspalace mentioned

Comment: @KThemes I'm still not clear why those can't be set when the user is initialized by passing values for the `first_name` and `last_name` keys. Why is the additional function necessary for these values?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you have some function hooked in the "pre_user_first_name" filter ($first_name = apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name);)

If you wanna check and be sure if there is any function hooked in there you can use this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224209/wordpress-how-do-i-get-all-the-registered-functions-for-the-content-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wp_insert_user, you could try running  `update_user_meta( $new_user_id, "first_name",  $ext_user['firstName'] ) ;`

Answer (score 1):

This code works when I try it, though it generates an "undefinded variable" error (looks like you should pass a user password). However, there are a [number of filters in there that could be used to manipulate the data.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1320) including `pre_user_first_name` and `pre_user_last_name`. As those fields are "meta" fields, it would also be possible to alter the data via filters run by `update_user_meta()`.  That data is passed through `update_metadata()` which [allows selective filtering](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L122).

I can only assume that one or more of those filters are involved in creating this issue.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I'm not sure how to act on this information.

Comment: You will need to search your theme and plugins for callbacks attached to those several hooks, and hopefully locate what is breaking the user insertion. You should not have to run `update_user_meta()` after `wp_insert_user()`, as suggested in a comment to the question, because [it should have already ran](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1423).